# Generating consumer key and consumer secret in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to integrate the WSO2 API Manager with a website so that the user doesn't need to login to the API Store.

From what I can see there is a stumbling block, in that the user needs to click on the 'Generate' button in the store in order to first generate the consumer key and secret.

Once this has been done then on it is possible to call the subscription API and generate token API as documented:

```
$ curl -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-list/ajax/subscription-list.jag?action=getAllSubscriptions
{
   "error" : false,
   "subscriptions" : [
      {
      {
         "sandRegenarateOption" : true,
         "prodKey" : "2486e65cbac4e372fb319375744fb",
         "subscriptions" : [
            {
               ...
               "prodConsumerSecret" : "Tx9i9WYu6_a3qqW08bF7jEG660",
               "prodConsumerKey" : "VfS5r5u4rFhec2vVBlFosxRgcE",
               "prodAuthorizedDomains" : "ALL"
               ...
            }
         ],
         ...
         "prodConsumerSecret" : "Tx9i9WYu6_a3qqW08bF7jEG660",
         "prodConsumerKey" : "VfS5r5u4rFhec2vVBlFosxRgcE"
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

However until the 'Generate' button has been clicked in the browser, the values above are `null`

When I tried using the suggestion:

```
$ curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d "action=generateApplicationKey&application=4&keytype=PRODUCTION&provider=admin&tier=Unlimited&version=0.1&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains="
```

The server logs:

```
ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:4
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Application should be approved before registering.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:1678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:34)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:649)
```

But according to the getApplications API it is approved already:

```
curl -b cookies   http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag?action=getApplications
{
   "applications" : [
      ...
      {
         "tier" : "Unlimited",
         "status" : "APPROVED",
         "callbackUrl" : "",
         "name" : "app2",
         "id" : 4,
         "description" : ""
      }
   ],
   "error" : false
}
```

Any more thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following REST invocation

```
curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d "action=generateApplicationKey&application=DefaultApplication&keytype=PRODUCTION&provider=admin&tier=Unlimited&version=1.0.0&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains="
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked... I get an error message and in the logs I see the following:  
     ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:4
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Application should be approved before registering.  

But according to the application-list/ajax/application-list.jag?action=getApplications API, the application is showing as approved :(

Comment: I'll add this to the question so I can format it better

Comment: Thanks...
It took me a while to figure out what I was doing wrong... the application is the name of the application, where as for other APIs its the applicationId that is required... my bad :)

Comment: Dan Can you post your REST call as a comment please

Comment: I'll post it as an edit to the main posting... the formatting is quite poor in comments afaics

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any direct way to get that done. But you can make use of [Store API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Store+APIs) exposed by wso2 API manger and retrieve all the subscription and from that you can filter the required ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret.

I have tried this and worked pretty well to me :)

Comment: Hi @Vanji, thanks for the comment. Like you I can get the subscriptions and if a key has already been generated. The problem is getting the key to be generated without using a browser and having the user click 'Generate'...

Answer (score 0):

You need to promote before subscribing. You need to call "/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag" endpoint with "PUBLISHED" status and "updateStatus" action. Once it is in promoted state you can subscribe to it.

Comment: Curious, because I have two other subscriptions through other apps and these seem OK. Also the API is in PUBLISHED state, which is what I think you are suggesting needs to happen.<br/>I'll check everything again over the weekend when I have some more time and post an update. Thanks for your comments and help